# How can I get some component information on Forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

**How can I get some component information on Forge viewer?**

When I click a column or beam, I want get it`s property(name,id...).
Suppose it has property.

Which API can use?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewer provides getProperties that sends back all properties of an object. The code below is a demo. It assumes some objects have been selected. If you have delegated SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event.dbIdArray returns the selection set.

```
 //get selection set (DbIds array)
 var sel = myviewer.getSelection();

 //if we only want to check the first object in the selected set
 myviewer.getProperties(sel[0],function(objProp){ 

 if(objProp){

         console.log(objProp);

         //iterate each property
         for(var index in objProp.properties){
             var Prop = objProp.properties[index];
             console.log('name: ' + Prop.displayName + ' value:' 
          +Prop.displayValue);
         } 
    } 
});
```

if you want to get one specific property, you can use viewer.model.getBulkProperties. The blog tells more
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method